# why ToList() doesnt work in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

i am having a issue while sorting data with more than a field

here is sample code i have used :

```
 var Item = from itm in DB.Items
select new Item
{
};
return Item.ToList().OrderBy(e => e.ExpiryDate).ToList();
```

above code does'nt show any error but also doesn sort with expirydate field :(

if i use like this

```
return Item.OrderBy(e => e.ExpiryDate).ToList();
```

this gives a error that sql doesnt contain translation for orderby

any help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

I think there are a couple things going on here. First, you've named your result variable the same as the class you're creating in the `select`. Probably doesn't make much difference, but it's confusing. Let's change it:

```
var items = from itm in DB.Items
            select new Item
            {
            };
```

Next, your `DB.Items` context is already built of `Item` objects. You don't need to create new ones. In the above code, your new `Item` objects are empty anyway.

```
var items = from itm in DB.Items
            select itm;
```

If you want to order them right away, you can do that too:

```
var items = from itm in DB.Items
            orderby itm.ExpiryDate
            select itm;
```

If you need that as a `List`, you can do that in the same line:

```
var items = (from itm in DB.Items
             orderby itm.ExpiryDate
             select itm).ToList();
```

Now `items` will be a concrete `List` of `Item` objects (`List<Item>`).

Answer (score 5):

Your code creates instances of `Item` using the default constructor, without passing anything that you get from the DB to it. That is why you get a list of identical empty items; sorting them has no effect.

Remove the first `Select` to make it work:

```
var Item = DB.Items; // No "Select ..."
return Item.ToList().OrderBy(e => e.ExpiryDate).ToList();
```

Your first `ToList` forces the data into memory, where `OrderBy` can be applied. You can replace it with an `AsEnumerable()` call as well, to avoid creating a list in memory for the second time:

```
return Item.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(e => e.ExpiryDate).ToList();
```

Comment: You should replace the first `ToList` with `AsEnumerable`.  It will make sure that the order by is executed as linq to objects rather than executed on the DB, but without consuming so much memory by creating and then discarding a list.  I'd also be very surprised to find a query provider that can't do an order by, and it really should be done on the DB end if possible.